# .rename() function seems to be doing nothing?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Very new to Python, and my first post here, so please be forgiving :)

I'm trying to rename some columns in a dataframe, but Python is not having it! There's no error being thrown up, but nothing's changing.

I tried the following:

```
f_G.rename(columns = {'0':'Genre 1', '1':'Genre 2', '2':'Genre 3'}, inplace = True)
```

I was expecting the columns to be renamed to 'Genre 1', etc., but instead they're remaining as 0, 1, 2.

[What's being shown to me after applying .rename()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4HxTb.png)

Comment: Python doesn't have dataframes. Please always include the [tag:pandas] tag when asking pandas questions, as described in the [tag:python] tag wiki: "When using a Python variant (e.g. Jython, PyPy) or library (e.g. Pandas, NumPy), please include it in the tags."

Comment: Check f_G.columns.dtype. Are they strings or integers?

Comment: Alternatively you can just do `f_G.columns = ['Genre 1', 'Genre 2', 'Genre 3']`

Comment: They're probably integers, so you'll just need to use `0: 'Genre 1'` for example. BTW, welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour] and [ask].

Answer (score 0):

It's likely your current column names are integers and not strings (e.g. renaming '0' won't do anything since it's column 0).

```
f_G.rename(columns = {0:'Genre 1', 1:'Genre 2', 2:'Genre 3'}, inplace = True)
```